# Is there any reward for getting all the animus fragments in Assassin's Creed Revelations?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In Assassin's Creed: Revelations, is there any reward for collecting all 100 animus fragments, other than a trophy/achievement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have all of the Desmond memories (at 30), and the maps (for the Memoir Pages at 25 and the remaining fragment locations at 50), there are [no other rewards](http://www.gamecheatsmaster.net/cheats/unlockable--data-fragment-rewards) besides the achievement at 100.

Answer (score 4):

I can't remember getting anything other than the achievement.

In other games you would receive a cape or something. Here, I can't remember.